# Making particles "twinkle" with a custom shader

Tags: glsl, three.js

I'm making a night sky and I'd like the stars in my ParticleSystem to twinkle.

I've heard that I can use a noise texture for randomness, but I'm not sure where to go from there.  And I'm not sure how to make the twinkle happen smoothly, ie. get brighter gradually and then dimmer.

Right now I am just giving each vertex a random `rand` attribute, and then changing a uniform `twinkleRand` every 200ms or so.  If the randoms match, the point becomes larger:

```
if (rand == twinkleRand) {
   gl_PointSize = size * abs(sin(js_time) + rand/100.);
}
else {
   gl_PointSize = size;
}
```

It's sort of twinkly but not quite a convincing effect.

Comment: +1 Once I get new votes. I already liked the question, but `It's sort of twinkly` really got me hooked =)

Comment: @ty Can you add a small jsfiddle example for us to experiment on??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rather than changing the point size, change the color -- you'll get a more natural, less pulsing look. And give each star a unique persistent values, so that they twinkle, rather than strobe.

```
newColor = starColor * (1.0 - (sin(js_time*starSpeed)+1.0)*starVariance*0.5)
```